# Check if a string contains a character and also doesn't contain another

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
if (article.find("(")) and not (article.find(")")):
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `find` returns -1 if the needle isn't found, which counts as True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in` , `and not in`.

```
if '(' in article and not ')' in article:
```

**Example:**

```
>>> a = '(sdk'
>>> if '(' in a and not ')' in a:
        print('yah')


yah
>>> a = '(sdk)'
>>> if '(' in a and not ')' in a:
        print('yah')


>>> a = 'sdk'
>>> if '(' in a and not ')' in a:
        print('yah')


>>>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.

Comment: `')' not in article:` works equally well as `not ')' in article:`, and reads a bit more like English.

Answer (score 2):

```
Help on built-in function find:

find(...)
    S.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int

    Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
    such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
    arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

    Return -1 on failure.
```

You want something that returns 0 on failure. The `in` operator does that.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> x = 'Hello ( world'
>>> '(' in x
True
>>> ')' in x
False
>>>
```